# Pull latest changes from Github repo at boot via systemd service

Tags: ssh, systemd

When my device boots (a Raspberry Pi Zero W), I start a systemd service that is responsible for executing a script called `start.sh`, which in turn runs my `main.py` Python script (in addition to other things).

I would like `start.sh` to pull changes from Github before running `main.py`. My first attempt was simply to add a `git pull`, but I'm seeing the error `Host key verification failed.`

I'm assuming this is somehow related to the systemd services's access to SSH keys for Github authentication, but I don't know how to enable SSH for systemd as needed.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an approach that achieves what I was trying to accomplish.

Github offers the ability to create [deploy keys](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys), which can provide read-only SSH access to a repo.

I created a new key SSH without a passphrase, added this as a read-only deploy key to my repo, and can now automatically pull changes from the repo with the script triggered from the systemd service on boot.

It's worth noting that SSH keys without passphrases are much less secure than when protected by a passphrase, but this is a compromise I'm willing to make since the key only provides read-only access.

Answer (score 1):

It may be prompting to accept the remote server's host key - can you run it directly first to make sure the entry is in `known_hosts`? Also confirm the `User` in your `[Service]` section is correct.

Comment: Thanks — I've added `User=pi`, but now I'm getting `Permission denied (publickey).`

Answer (score 0):

```
Host key verification failed.
```

Normally means that the identity of the server on the other side has changed the identity or you didn't have added the host key to you `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file.

Try to pull from the same repository with the user that run this script.
Or you could try to remove the the old host key with `ssh-keygen -R [hostname/ip]`.

If you are using ssh-keys for authentication please make also sure that the ssh key is in the folder `~/.ssh/` of the user that run this script.

Comment: I can pull from the repo as a the `pi` user, but the pull fails when executed from the systemd unit.